# Can't use Google Play Services on emulator android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I can't use Google Play services with the emulators in Android Studio. I give you my build.gradle and manifest files:

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fr.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}



dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Part of my AndroidManifest (I don't show all the activities):

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

    <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And in a xml I just have the google button : com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton

And when I lauch my Application, when I arrive in the activity containing the button, I have the following message : "**the app won't run unless you update Google Play services**". I also have (I tried some solutions) "**this app won't run without Google Play services, which are missing from your phone**".

I've found some questions on this problem, but it always said that the last emulator don't have this problem. But using the default Nexus 5 (API 22) emulator on android studio gives me these errors. So I tried to install the last apk google play services file, and after successing the install, I launch the app and have this time this error : "**the app relies on Google play services, which is not supported by your device. Contact the manufacturer for assistance.**" I also tried with a virtual device that I created, with API 22 and 23 and I have the same errors.

I don't understand because I thought that the errors with Google play services didn't exist anymore on the last API.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to create emulator with image x86 which includes Google APIs

[image]